# generative question answering huggingface model

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering, sequence-to-sequence

Is there an open-source generative question-answering model on huggingface where we can provide a large document as KB (Knowledge Base) such that given a question related to that KB, the model outputs a relevant answer?

Comment: Define large. The [EleutherAI](https://huggingface.co/EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B) models are able to process up to 2048 tokens.

Comment: Is the length of the Knowledge base bound by max token length supported? I was under the impression that only question length is bounded by token length. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: All of your input and the generated output need to be smaller than the supported max_length of the model.